# "Rate this application button" in NEW application

Tags: ios, app-store

There are a lot of suggestions how to add a "Rate this application **button**" to the app.

I have this **button** and I'm going to send my application to the first review.

Also in my app I have an ability to send message with the **link** to this application.

**Link** and **button** will work correctly when the app is approved.

But during approval they won't work correctly, will they?

My question is:

***Will my app be rejected during the review process?***

***If it will be rejected then what should I do?***

Comment: It'll open the app store, and the app store shows "this app is currently not available". That's most likely good enough. I don't see a problem with the review team. They will probably understand that "Rate my App" is not possible when the app has not launched.

Comment: Hope you'r right! Will submit it the way it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how exactly you determine the AppStore URL for the rate button (I personally like [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate)), but what about just hiding the button/mail feature if the AppStore URL for your app couldn't be determined?

Comment: That is what I'm going to do if the application will be rejected!